# how to detect caps lock key tap in iOS keyboard for UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

How to detect if the user tapped on the caps lock button in iOS keyboard?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        print(string)
        return true

    }
```

This method is getting called for text changes in textField. is there any other way?

Why I want to know if the caps lock button is tapped is because My right view and caps lock icon of apple are overlapping when the user tapped on the caps lock button.

Comment: Can you share the screen shot for this _My right view and caps lock icon of apple are overlapping when the user tapped on the caps lock button._, because I couldn't understand how keyboard Caps is overlapped by your view.

Comment: When you tap on caps lock button, at the tight side of textField it shows caps lock symbol.

Comment: Then, hide the default caps lock shown in UITextField.

Answer (score 0):

When ever the caps lock gets on, iOS shows `shift-up` symbol at right side of `UITextField`. The caps lock icon basically will be set inside [rightView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619596-rightview) of UITextField, if you see the view hierarchy.

[image]

So, set `rightView` to a `UIView` with `frame` as `zero`.

```
myTextField.rightView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

Comment: that will hide my custom rightView as well. for my case, it's eye icon to show and hide.